# RPGLE/free - dynamically specify data area library

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Is there a way to dynamically specify data area library, either directly or indirectly.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a variable name in the `dtaara()` keyword...
**EDIT**
Per Barbara's comments, the variable must have a value before the `IN` op-code is used on a user controlled data area (ie. `*AUTO` is ***NOT*** specified.)

The below section of the doc's only apply when `*AUTO` is used.
**/EDIT**

However, that variable must have a value when the program starts.  From the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=keywords-dtaara-keyword#ddtaara__dtaaraname):

> Attention: If you specify a variable for the name of a data area data
> structure, then this variable must have the value set before the
> program starts. This can be done by initializing the variable, passing
> the variable as an entry parameter, or sharing the variable with
> another program through the IMPORT and EXPORT keywords.

So you'd want a char(21) variable passed (or imported) into the program and then make sure that the value being passed is one of the following:
You can specify the value in any of the following forms:
`dtaaraname`
`libname/dtaaraname`
`*LIBL/dtaaraname`

Comment: The variable only has to be set before the program starts when it is defined with DTAARA(*AUTO) (or UDS in fixed form). 

With the simple DTAARA keyword, you don't need to have the variable set until you do the IN operation.

Comment: Charles, that bit of documentation is about a "data area data structure". I see where that can be confusing when the variable with the DTAARA keyword is a data structure, but "data area data structure" specifically means *AUTO. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=keyword-free-form-dtaara-data-structure

Comment: @BarbaraMorris if you want to add a better answer, I for one would up vote it.  Otherwise I'll edit my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: Sorry Charles. I didn't see your message until just now. I think your edit is fine.